# Failed to add this package (flutter_native_splash ^1.2.0 and flutter_launcher_icons 0.7.3, version solving failed.)

Tags: flutter, icons, flutter-dependencies, splash-screen

I was trying to add [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) but this I got this error

> Because flutter_launcher_icons >=0.7.1 <0.9.0 depends on yaml ^2.1.15 and flutter_native_splash 1.2.0 depends on yaml ^3.1.0, flutter_launcher_icons >=0.7.1 <0.9.0 is incompatible with flutter_native_splash 1.2.0. And because no versions of flutter_native_splash match >1.2.0 <2.0.0, flutter_launcher_icons >=0.7.1 <0.9.0 is incompatible with flutter_native_splash ^1.2.0. So, because <project_name> depends on both flutter_native_splash ^1.2.0 and flutter_launcher_icons 0.7.3, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; So, because <project_name> depends on both flutter_native_splash ^1.2.0 and flutter_launcher_icons 0.7.3, version solving failed.)
> exit code 1

How to solve this problem? or is there a compatible version to sync [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) with [flutter_native_screen](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is due to version incompatibilities in pubspec.yaml. fix them by comparing and testing versions